# Explicit examples presheaves associated to higher direct images which fail to be sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

So I would like to have a few simple examples where the presheaf associated to higher direct image of sheaf fails to be sheaf. So I'm looking for two (natural and simple) topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, a continuous map $f:X\rightarrow Y$
and a sheaf of abelian groups $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ such that the presheaf $f_*^{i}(\mathcal{F})$ given by 
$$
U\mapsto H^i(f^{-1}(U),\mathcal{F}|_{f^{-1}(U)})
$$ 
(for some $i>0$) fails to be a sheaf on $Y$.

I'd like to see the two possible obstructions for $f_*^{i}(\mathcal{F})$ to be a sheaf namely

(i) the impossibility of gluing local sections of $f_*^{i}(\mathcal{F})$ to a global one,

(ii) the existence of a **non-zero** global section of $f_*^{i}(\mathcal{F})$ which is trivial at each stalk $y\in Y$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For (i), take $X=S^3$, $Y= S^2$, $f$ the Hopf fibration. There is a local $H^1$ everywhere, coming from the fact that the fibers are circles. This local section is defined consistently everywhere (because there is no monodromy since $Y$ is simply-connected), but it does not glue to a global section because $H^1(X,\mathbb Z)=0$.

For (ii), simply take $X=Y$ a manifold space with nontrivial cohomology and $\mathcal F$ the constant sheaf. Then there is a global section corresponding to the higher cohomology classes. This section vanishes on every open ball, so it vanishes on every stalk.

Comment: As to the first case, why don't the local sections glue to a global one? What's wrong with $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Because the Leray spectral sequence does not degenerate at the second page. The $H^1(X,\mathbb Z)$ coming from $H^0 R^1$ cancels with the $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ coming from $H^2 R^0$, leading to vanishing cohomology groups. Less abstractly, the nontrivial $H_1$ class of a fiber is represented by the full fiber, a circle. This circle is a trivial homology class because it bounds a disc in $S^3$. This disc wraps all the way around $S^2$, becoming the nontrivial homology class in $S^2$, but in $S^3$ one bounds the other so they cancel each other out.

Comment: For (i), $f$ is a fibration with fibre $S^1$ and so $f^1_*(\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$ is a locally constant sheaf with fibre $\mathbb{Z}$. As $S^2$ is simply connected, we have $f_*^1$ is the constant sheaf, so I don't agree that (i) is an example. $f^3_*$ would however give an example for (ii).

Comment: The pushforward presheaf is locally constant but not a sheaf. The sheafification, as you point out, is the constant sheaf. So it has a global section. But the presheaf does not have any sections on all of $Y$, because these are just defined to be $H^1(X, \mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you were saying. I agree with (i) now.

Comment: Thanks a lot Will for answering my basic questions of sheaf theory. I'm really struggling to learn this theory. Do you know a good reference where one gives many examples of presheaves and sheaves and how the various presheaves we meet in topology (tensor prodcut, inverse image, higher direct images ...) may fail to be sheaves, and how this failure can be read from data in spectral sequences.

Comment: I do not know a good reference.

Comment: Hi Will may I ask why the trivial monodromy implies the consistence of the local sections? Do you mean taking parallel transport locally to gaurantee the consistency but why parallel transport can not use to construct global section?

Comment: @yili This has little to do with parallel transport. For one, the sections being translated are not sections of the tangent bundle but rather classes in cohomology groups. You are (I think) trying to use some geometric intuition here. The issue with applying geometric intuition to thinking about sections is that when you think about sections geometrically as sections of an actual bundle, the sheaf axiom (that sections defined over some open sets which agree on the intersections of those open sets glue to a global section) is a tautology.

Comment: @yili But here we're dealing with a presheaf where the sheaf axiom does not hold. So one just has to rely on the formal definition, which merely says that over each open set we have a set of sections. Locally this presheaf agrees with a sheaf, and that sheaf has trivial monodromy (the way I formulated it, it doesn't come from a vector bundle, but I could have constructed it from a vector bundle with flat connection, and used the fact that every vector bundle with flat connection on $S^2$ is trivial). So I can choose a global section of the sheaf

Comment: and find local sections of the presheaf that agree with it locally everywhere. But this doesn't imply anything about global sections because these are a formal notion and we have to go to the definition of this presheaf, which says the global sections vanish.

Comment: Ok got it, thank you for your nice explaination, Will.